# Changing ArcGIS Server URL and reestablishing links to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.3

I've migrated the location of my ArcGis Server and changed the base URL I will be using with my services.   Is it possible to automate the process of reconnecting my services in ArcGIS online with the new server URL or do I have to do it manually?

I'm using 10.3 Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools out there like this one:
https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools/blob/master/samples/updateMapServiceUrlsInWebMaps.py

You can also use http://ago-assistant.esri.com/ to update the URLs but it will be a manual job in this case.

Russ

Comment: The `ArcGIS Online Assistant` link has no documentation and requires an organizational password upfront...What is that?

Comment: This link can help you out: https://github.com/Esri/ago-assistant